# Set listening IP address for "ADB over network", debug over OpenVPN connection

Tags: android, debugging, adb, wifi, openvpn

In developer options (Android 7.1.2), I can activate "ADB over network". It automatically sets the IP address where ADB listens to the one of the devices WiFi interface.

For added security and flexibility (I'd like to debug in a cafe with public WiFi), I would like ADB to listen on the IP address of my OpenVPN tunnel. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you achieved any results? Trying to do the same here

Answer (score 1):

I had the same query and found your post.
I tried it, and although it doesn't show the IP assigned by the VPN server, you still can get adb to connect with that IP.
Whether or not it can be connected to with the displayed IP, I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting, though I'd want to make sure that it's *only* listening to the VPN address.